# How to execute multiple runs/compilations to check testfiles with l3build?

Tags: l3build

I want to use `l3build` to perform regression tests on some LaTeX code that I have.
My difficulties start when I need multiple compilation to do such regression tests.
For example, I want to check if a table of content is correctly printing the sections of my test-document.

If, I do it manually, with the 1st compilation, the table of content is missing, and at 2nd compilation everything is fine. But, if I do it with `l3build` I do not manage to compile a 2nd time.

From the documentation, I found that `runtest_tasks` could be an option.
However, it seems not to work correctly in my case.
I think that I missed a little something, but since I found no example, it is hard for me to find this little something.

Here is a MWE:
build.lua:

```
checksearch = true -- Enable command printing during check phase

-- Function to check if a file name matches a certain pattern
local function match_pattern(filename, pattern)
  return true
  -- string.match(filename, pattern) ~=nil
end

-- Define the runtest_tasks function
runtest_tasks = function(name, run)
  if run == 1 then
    print("Debug: name =", name, "run =", run, current_engine )
    -- Run additional tasks for files matching a specific pattern
    if match_pattern(name, "mytest") then
      print("")
      print("Executing additional tasks for files matching the pattern.")
      print("tex(name)")
      -- Add your specific tasks here
      errorlevel = tex(name..'.lvt') -- second compilation
      print("Executing additional tasks DONE")
      return "echo "..errorlevel -- I get 256, and no table of content printed
    else
      return "echo "..0
    end
  else
    return "echo "..0
  end
end
```

and a mytest.lvt

```
\input regression-test.tex\relax

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\START
\showoutput


\TEST{toc section}{

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{test}

}
\END 

\vfil\break
\end{document}
```

So how to perform a regression test with `l3build` requiring multiple runs/compilations ?

Comment: typically you simply set the checkruns variable, e.g. `checkruns=3`.

Comment: Humm humm, Yes, I missed that option in the documentation... I was probably working too late yesterday... Additionally, can this option be set only for some testfiles ?

Comment: you can separate testfiles in different folders and use a config-file to change the settings.

Comment: If you want to turn your comments into an anwser, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am turning @Ulrike Fischer comments into an anwser.

There is simply the option `checkruns=3` available for that purpose.
In addition, if the multiple checkruns are concerning only some files, they can be separated in a different folder and use the `checkconfigs={<file>}` option to point toward a specific setting configuration file related to that folder (and files).